# container transform between activity and fragment

Tags: android, material-design

I have 1 activity and 2 fragments. My activity have a FragmentContainerView to host the 2 fragments and a Floating Action Button. I want to do a ContainerTransform transforming the FAB in the second fragment when a navigate from first fragment to second fragment. This [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-android#4) did the enterTransiton, how i do the returnTransition work with ContainerTransform too?

I tried this:

MainActivity:

```
  private fun navigateToAddFragment() {
    val view = binding.fab
    val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(view to "shared_element_container")
    navController.navigate(
        R.id.action_tasksFragment_to_addTaskFragment,
        null,
        null,
        extras
    )
}
```

SecondFragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
        duration = 600
        this.isElevationShadowEnabled = false
        startElevation = 0F
        endElevation = 0F

        setPathMotion(MaterialArcMotion())
        startContainerColor = MaterialColors.getColor(
            requireContext(),
            com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorSurface,
            Color.BLACK
        )
        endContainerColor = MaterialColors.getColor(
            requireContext(),
            com.google.android.material.R.attr.colorSurface,
            Color.BLACK
        )

        this.startShapeAppearanceModel =
            ShapeAppearanceModel.Builder()
                .setAllCornerSizes(requireContext().dpToPixels(16F)).build()
        endShapeAppearanceModel =
            ShapeAppearanceModel.Builder()
                .setAllCornerSizes(requireContext().dpToPixels(16F)).build()
    }
}
```

note: i set Transitions names in xml.

Comment: Do you tried anything to show us?

Comment: Yes. I tried use the same transition is in enterTransition into returnTransitioon and set fab as endView, but not work. I'll edit the question and put the code i did.